# What is the definition of "Custom Action" in PnP?

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, pnp-powershell, custom-actions

I am an Admin for SP2010, SP2013 and SP2016 on-premise farm and I never use SP online before.

Recently I am checking the ability of [SharePoint PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) and found it also support SP2016 on-premise. There are some cmdlet related with Custom Action. But I am uncertain what is the definition of "custom action" now and I fail to find the definition in Microsoft website (maybe because the keyword "custom" and "action" is too generic).

My understanding can be summarized in below screenshot from SPD 2013.

[image: SPD 2013 custom action]

In our farm, several subsites have added custom actions on ribbon bar and list item menu using SPD 2013. However running `Get-PnPCustomAction` do not return anything.

My questions are:
1. Could I manage the custom action added by SPD using `Get-PnPCustomAction`?
2. What is "Custom Action" now?

Answer (score -1):

Check below official documentations to Get, Add and Remove custom actions.

You will also find the Parameters required for each command and different examples for the same:

1. [Get-PnPCustomAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpcustomaction).
2. [Add-PnPCustomAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpcustomaction).
3. [Remove-PnPCustomAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpcustomaction).

Comment: Sorry what is "custom action"?  All the link above explain how to use the cmdlet but they didn't mention what is custom action.

Comment: `Get-PnPCustomAction` command returns **[List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserCustomAction>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpcustomaction?view=sharepoint-ps#outputs)** which is list of `UserCustomAction` that [Represents a custom action associated with a SharePoint list, Web site, or subsite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee539583(v%3Doffice.15)).

Comment: I tried Get-PnPCustomAction and returned nothing. Is it means "Custom Action" created with SPD is not PnPCustomAction?